# Why does jQuery include an Origin header in my Ajax-requests and how to remove it from them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

For instance, an Ajax request:

```
$.post( 'http://example.com/script.pl', formdata, function ( data ) {
    // ...
});
```

But this request also includes an "Origin" header - even though it is *not* a cross-domain request.

Why is this header included in my Ajax-requests and how can I remove it from them?

Comment: @SLaks Thanks, I will try that (tomorrow - I don't have access to the server right now)

Answer (score 3):

If you are in Chrome (and WebKit?), the "Origin" header is always included on POST, PUT and DELETE requests. This is true for both same-domain and cross-domain requests. The "Origin" header is not included on same-domain GET requests. AFIAK, there is no way to remove this.

Comment: Your response helped me solve a similar problem (GET requests not being CORS requests) by finding https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50773 . Thank you.